# Configure Spring Security to allow requests to link

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have these links which I would like to use to get data without authentication:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/web_payment/wpf/3jeglsv7e5umcmz7e4b9wa6tq61v3q7a

POST http://localhost:8080/web_payment/en/payment/1234566666
```

I tried to use this Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value = { Application.class, ContextDatasource.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.datalis.web.payment.server.*" })
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    MerchantAuthService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*/payment/*").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/wpf/*").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

But when I make GET request to    `http://localhost:8080/web_payment/wpf/3jeglsv7e5umcmz7e4b9wa6tq61v3q7a`

I get

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Map>
    <timestamp>1552646237152</timestamp>
    <status>401</status>
    <error>Unauthorized</error>
    <message>Unauthorized</message>
    <path>/web_payment/wpf/3jeglsv7e5umcmz7e4b9wa6tq61v3q7a</path>
</Map>
```

Do you know what configuration I need to apply in order to apply access only to these links?

Comment: re-validate your antmatchers syntax. I think the problem lies there

Comment: Are you sure, that your configuration is executed? Add a breakpoint to your code and see if it is reached.